# SQLAlchemy join logic between

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have 3 Models.

1. I have a user model: User(id)
2. Benefit model: Benefit(name, start_date, end_date, user_id) # if end date is None, it means its current
3. Receipt model: Receipt(id, date, member_id)

I'm trying to get all receipts, the user id they belong to and the benefit that was in place when the receipt happened.

```
query = session.query(Receipt, User.id, Benefit.name)
       .filter(Receipt.date <= some_date)
       .join(User, User.id == Receipt.member_id)
       .join(Benefit, and_(Benefit.user_id == User.id,
           Benefit.start_date < Receipt.date < Benefit.end_date)) # if Benefit.end_date exist else datetime.now()
df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind)
```

What would be the best way to deal with the last join where `Benefit.end_date` might be none?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `or_` condition checking if `Benefit.end_date` is `None`

```py
query = session.query(Receipt, User.id, Benefit.name)
       .filter(Receipt.date <= some_date)
       .join(User, User.id == Receipt.member_id)
       .join(Benefit, and_(
           Benefit.user_id == User.id,
           or_(
               Benefit.start_date < Receipt.date < Benefit.end_date,
               and_(
                    Benefit.end_date.is_(None),
                    Benefit.start_date < Receipt.date < datetime.now()
               )
           )
       )
```

Performance-wise it will be the same but I think it would be easier to read when all conditions go to `filter` section:

```py
query = session.query(Receipt, User.id, Benefit.name)
       .join(User, User.id == Receipt.member_id)
       .join(Benefit, Benefit.user_id == User.id)
       .filter(
           Receipt.date <= some_date,
           or_(
               Benefit.start_date < Receipt.date < Benefit.end_date,
               and_(
                    Benefit.end_date.is_(None),
                    Benefit.start_date < Receipt.date < datetime.now()
               )
           )
       )
```